# Lebesgue inner measure is translation invariant

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I am trying to show that lebesgue inner measure is translation invariant for bounded set. The lebesgue inner measure is defined as follows for bounded set:

$m_*(A)=|I|-m^*(I-A)$, where $m^*(A)$ is the lebesgue outer measure for $A$, $A \subset I$.

I know that lebesgue outer measure is translation invariant.

Answer (score 0):

See this post, [Inner and outer Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499745/inner-and-outer-lebesgue-measure) and the PDF linked there, http://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/talks/Measure-Theory.pdf. From those, we know that if $E$ is Lebesgue outer measurable, then $m_*(E) = m^*(E)$. Suppose $E$ is measurable. Then for $h \in \mathbb{R}$, $E + h$ is outer measurable, and \begin{align*}
   m_*(E+h) = m^*(E+h) = m^*(E) = m_*(E)
\end{align*}
Thus $m_*$ is translation invariant.

Comment: There is no need here for $E$ to be measurable, though

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're right, I'm (unfortunately) using an extra hypothesis. You should be able to prove this without assuming $E$ is outer measureable.