# How does the frequentist definition of probability work with non-measurable sets?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-sets, oracles

Let $E$ be a subset of $[0,1]$, and let us try to create a measure of $E$ as follows.  Let $x_1,x_2,...$ be a sequence of independent random real numbers picked using a uniform probability distribution on the interval $[0,1]$, and let us send each $x_n$ through an oracle which tells us whether $x_n\in E$ or not.  And then let us define the measure of $E$ to be the limit of the fraction of the first $n$ elements which are in $E$, as $n$ goes to infinity.

My question is, for what sets $E$ does this limit exist?  Does it exist for all sets $E$, or only for Lebesgue-measurable sets, or what?  What exactly happens when you try the procedure for non-Lebesgue measurable sets?  Will the limit just diverge?

Comment: Note that for _any_ set (apart from the empty set and the whole set) E could be anything in $[0,1]$, or just not converge. Presumably, for a set with measure $k$, the probability that $E$ exists and $E=k$ is $1$. I don't know what happens with non-measurable sets.

Comment: Any particular sequence $x_n$ has only countably many values, so there are plenty of sets of measure $1$ for which the limit is $0$, and plenty of sets of measure $0$ for which the limit is $1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Well, at least for a Lebesgue measurable set $E$, if we choose each $x_i$ using a uniform probability distribution on $0,1]$, I’m pretty sure that with probability one the limit will converge to the Lebesgue measure of $E$.

Comment: Yes if you first fix a measurable set $E$, then almost surely the sequence will give you a limit of $m(E)$.  But I'm talking about a different scenario, where you first take the sequence $x_n$.  For any given sequence $x_n$, there will be measurable sets $E$ where you don't get a limit of $m(E)$.

Comment: These comments are a little confusing. I assume the question is referring to a sequence of iid uniform random variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ (even though it is not explicitly stated, and it would be more conventional to use capital letters as well...) in which case the question is well-defined and interesting. Arthur seems to have confused the set $E$ with its "measure", which is counter to the point of the question ("what happens when $E$ is non-measurable") - so I don't know how to parse Arthur's comment in an interesting way. Robert's comment concerns deterministic sequences unlike the question

Comment: @pre-kidney Yes, I am talking about a sequence of uniform random variables.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Well, regardless my question is about the first kind of scenario.  I want to know what would happen if we fix a non-measurable set, and then take a randomly generated sequence.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan what I was trying to point out in my last comment is that you omitted the independence assumption, without which your question is meaningless. You still have not mentioned it, but I am assuming it is what you mean. (For instance, if you omit this assumption you can get very boring examples, like a "random constant sequence" $x,x,x,\ldots$ where $x$ is uniformly random in $[0,1]$)

Comment: @pre-kidney Yes, I am assuming independence.

Comment: I have edited your question to include this assumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Initial answer:**
I don't have a rigorous answer for you, but let me point out that every subset of $[0,1]$ (measurable or not) has a rigorously defined inner and outer Lebesgue measure, both of which belong to $[0,1]$ and satisfy the expected inequality. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure#Definition) and links therein and related [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499745/inner-and-outer-lebesgue-measure) [on](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590243/examples-of-non-measurable-setslebesgue?rq=1) [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123251/lebesgue-inner-measure-is-translation-invariant?noredirect=1&lq=1) [site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742074/outer-measure-and-caratheodorys-criterion?rq=1).

I believe that the sequence you asked about will generally have liminf equal to the inner measure of $E$ and limsup equal to the outer measure of $E$. So for a non-measurable set where the inner and outer measures differ, the sequence will not converge to any particular value.

---

**Complete answer after discussion in comments:** [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.3187.pdf) posted by Keshav in the comments below provides a resolution of this question, which also happens to show the following:

1. My conjecture that the liminf and limsup equal the inner and outer measures is incorrect.
2. My second sentence "So for a non-measurable set where the inner and outer measures differ, the sequence will not converge to any particular value." is however correct.

Both statements follow from Theorem 1.3 in the linked paper. Indeed, the sequence of indicator functions $X_i=1_{x_i\in E}$ satisfy the paper's definition of an "iidpnmrvs" sequence (i.e., a sequence of iid possibly non-measurable random variables) and moreover the lower and upper expectations as defined in the paper coincides with the inner and outer measures of $E$. Thus the theorem applies, and if we assume that $E$ is non-measurable, it follows that the lower and upper expectations are non-equal and therefore the theorem shows that all the events we are interested in are "maximally non-measurable", meaning that neither do they occur "with probability $1$", nor with "probability $0$" nor can we get any bounds on the probability - the set is too badly behaved (its inner measure is $0$ and its outer measure is $1$).

To see that this contradicts my conjecture (1), we can take the set $A$ in theorem 1.3 to be the singleton value $\{m_*(E)\}$ in part (i) of the theorem, and then take $A$ to be the singleton value $\{m^*(E)\}$ in part (ii). In both cases the theorem says that the event that the corresponding limit equals the corresponding measure *does not* have probability $1$ (which is what my conjecture says, although I was not precise enough to include the "almost surely" in my statement).

To see that my conjectural statement (2) is correct, apply the theorem 1.3 with $A=\{a\}$ where $a$ is any deterministic element of $[m_*(E),m^*(E)]$. Then the theorem shows that the event that the sequence converges to $a$ (which is the intersection of the events in parts (i) and (ii) of the theorem) does not have probability $1$, which means that the sequence cannot converge to any deterministic a.s. limit.

Comment: Yeah, I’m familiar with Lebesgue inner measure and Lebesgue outer measure.  It would certainly be convenient for the liminf to be the Lebesgue inner measure and the limsup to be the Lebesgue outer measure, but why do think that it’s the case?

Comment: It's hard to even talk about non-measurable functions in the context of probability. By definition of Lesbegue outer measure there exists a union of intervals $F$ such that $m^*(E) \le m^*(F) \le m^*(E)+\epsilon$. Then $\limsup_{n\to\infty} n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{E}(x_i) \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{F}(x_i) = m^*(F)$, where the last equality holds almost surely by the law of large numbers an $m^*$ denotes the Lesbesgue outer measure.

Comment: So taking $\epsilon \to 0$ gives $\limsup_{n\to\infty} n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{E}(x_i) \le m^*(E)$ almost surely. A similar argument should apply to show the reverse inequality with the $\liminf$ and the inner measure.

Comment: Yes @eepperly16 it is not hard to show that all limit points of the sequence lie in $[m_*(E),m^*(E)]$ but the harder part is the reverse inequality, equivalent to finding a subsequence $n_k$ along which the fraction of points $\leq n_k$ lying in $E$ tends to $m_*(E)$ (respectively $m^*(E)$).

Comment: After thinking about my conjecture a little more, I am starting to doubt its veracity. For instance take a Vitali set in $[0,1]$ which has inner measure $0$ and outer measure $1$. I find it very hard to see how there could be any subsequence on which the limit tends to $1$.

Comment: @pre-kidney I found this paper which may be relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.3187.pdf

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan that paper is a very nice find and I believe it fully answers your question and disproves my conjecture. I will add the details to my answer.

Comment: What does the notation $1_{x_i\in E}$ mean? Does it mean $1_E(x_i)$?

Comment: No, remember $x_i$ is a random variable, so $x_i\in E$ is an event, and $1_{x_i\in E}$ is the random variable taking the value $1$ if $x_i$ falls in $E$ and $0$ otherwise. In fact, the probability space in this context is a space of sequences which can be written as $\Omega=[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ and $x_i$ is the random variable returning the $i^{th}$ entry of the sequence $\omega\in \Omega$, so that $1_{x_i\in E}$ is the random variable that returns $1$ if the $i^{th}$ entry of the sequence $\omega$ falls in $E$ and $0$ otherwise.